# How can I force a reload of an entity?

Tags: java, ajax, jpa, seam

I'm using a ajax4jsf poller `<a4j:poll>` to check whether an entity has been updated in the database by another process. I want to reload the entity each time.

How can I force a reload?

Calling `loadInstance()` seems to have has no effect. (Polling works as expected)

```
@Name("myComponentHome")
public class MyComponentHome extends EntityHome<ComponentType> {
     public void poll() {
        log.warn("poll");
        ComponentType loadInstance = loadInstance();
        if ( loadInstance.getReportTime() != null ) {
            log.warn("poll report detected stoping poller");
            setInstance( loadInstance() );
            pollEnabled = false;
        }
    }
...
}
```

Versions Seam 2.1.2 Jboss 4.2

EDIT:

Maybe it's easier to answer if one knows that Seams loadInstance() is implemented as:

```
return getEntityManager().find(getEntityClass(), getId());
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
getEntityManager().refresh(entity);
```